# PHP - echo result is only echoing email address from first result when submit button clicked

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I have a script which displays ads in a table based on a database query, each ad has a submit button, when the submit button is click it takes you to another page which echo's the corresponding details based on the username of the ad you clicked on, however when there is more than one ad, it only displays the details of the first ad. Is there any way to assign a unique ID or something so that when the submit button of a specific ad is clicked the corresponding details are echo'ed rather than just the first one?

This is the echo code:

```
echo "<div id='expanderContent' style='display:none'>
        <div class='reasonbar'>
          <div class='prod-title1' style='width: 70%;'>" . 
            $row['lname'] . 
          "</div>
          <div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>
            Category:<br /> ". 
            $row['category'] . 
          "</div>
        </div>";

echo "<div class='reasonbar'>
        <div class='prod-title2' style='width: 70%;'>
          <form action='adclick.php' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='username' value='" . $row['username'] . "'/>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
        </div>
        <div class='reason2' style='width: 29%;'>
        </div>
      </div
    </div>";
```

Comment: Are you pulling data from a database or what? We need more info and a  better code example to answer this

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes the data is coming from a database, the description explains my situation, basically trying to make it so that when a submit button (each ad has one) is clicked that it pulls the corresponding information for the one that was clicked?

Comment: please post your complete loop code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not closing your form tag in that echo. Second, do you have any kind of loop to go through multiple results (multiple ads) if more than one is retrieved?

Comment: @neeko Your second to last `div` tag isn't closed properly.

Comment: i think this has actually sorted it, thank you both for your replies! appollogise for my sloppy coding, i am very new to this!